# Freeing array of char pointers - only works when I have an even number of strings...?

Tags: c, memory-management

Having a super strange problem in C that I think is related to string memory management but I've poured through this code and can't tell what I'm doing wrong. I'm setting up an array of pointers to strings, where each string in the array is a token broken up from strtok(), which operates on a line made from getline using stdin.

I've been able to break apart the tokens, store them, and print the array with no problem. I just am having trouble freeing each individual pointer afterwards. I get an error message saying "invalid pointer", but oddly enough, it's only when I input an odd number of words in my original string. Even when I input an odd number of words in my string, it still breaks them apart into tokens and stores them in the array, its just the memory freeing that's failing.

here's a snippet of what I have:

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
getline(&line, &len, stdin);

char *token = strtok(line, " \n");

char **parsed = malloc(sizeof(char*));
if(parsed == NULL){
    printf("ruh roh scoob\n");
}

int numList = 0;
while(token!=NULL){
    numList++;
    parsed = realloc(parsed, sizeof(char*)*numList);
    if(parsed == NULL){
        printf("realloc failed :(\n");
    }

    int tokenLen = strlen(token);
    parsed[numList-1] = malloc(sizeof(char)*tokenLen);
    if(parsed[numList-1] == NULL){
        printf("ruh roh raggy\n");
    }

    strcpy(parsed[numList-1], token);

    token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
}
parsed[numList] = NULL;

for(int i = 0; i <= numList; i++){
    printf("%d-%s", i, parsed[i]);
}
printf("\n");

for(int j = 0; j < numList; j++){
    free(parsed[j]);
}
```

I thought I was allocating memory correctly and storing the data from my token pointers into the new pointers correctly but perhaps I was wrong. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: At a quick glance, it appears that you have forgotten to allow space for the (required) nul-terminator in your `malloc` calls.

Comment: `parsed[numList] = NULL;` writes one after the valid range of `parsed`. You also try to print out the `NULL` at the end in `(int i = 0; i <= numList; i++)`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop you call:

```
strcpy(parsed[numList-1], token);
```

This needs at least `strlen(token) + 1` bytes, but you're allocating one too few:

```
int tokenLen = strlen(token);
parsed[numList-1] = malloc(sizeof(char)*tokenLen);
```

So the `strcpy` writes past end of buffer, probably corrupting malloc metadata on a random basis. Note that you may get away with a write past end of buffer, because `malloc` rounds up the allocation amount, both to avoid memory fragmentation and to ensure that dynamically allocated buffers keep proper alignment (for better performance).

Comment: Note that you can avoid such errors, and do away with separate calls to `malloc` and `strcpy`, by using the [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) function.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried changing it so that `tokenLen = strlen(token) + 1`, but it's giving me the exact same error. I also tried using @AdrianMole's suggestion, bypassing malloc and strcpy by just using `parsed[i] = strdup(token)`, but it's again giving me issues where I can only input an even number of tokens. Not really sure what to try now.

Comment: I see, there is one more off-by-one error. Your `numList` counts the number of parsed tokens. However, you terminate the list with a `NULL` pointer, so you need space for one more. Allocate with `parsed = realloc(parsed, sizeof(char*)*(numList+1));`